# r collapsing data from multiple columns into one

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I know there are many questions on this topic so I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I'm trying to collapse multiple columns in a data set into one column:

Assuming this is the structure of the dataset I am working with,

```
df <- data.frame(
      cbind(
      variable_1 = c('Var1', NA, NA,'Var1'),
      variable_2 = c('Var2', 'No', NA, NA),
      variable_3 = c(NA, NA, 'Var3', NA),
      variable_4 = c(NA, 'Var4', NA, NA),
      variable_5 = c(NA, 'No', 'Var5', NA),
      variable_6 = c(NA, NA, 'Var6', NA)
      
    ))

 variable_1  variable_2  variable_3  variable_4  variable_5  variable_6 
 Var1        Var2        NA          NA          NA          NA
 NA          No          NA          Var4        No          NA
 NA          NA          Var3        NA          Var5        Var6
 Var1        NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

What I am expecting is a one column `variable_7` like this

```
 variable_1  variable_2  variable_3  variable_4  variable_5  variable_6  variable_7
 Var1        Var2        NA          NA          NA          NA          Var1, Var2
 NA          No          NA          Var4        No          NA          Var4
 NA          NA          Var3        NA          Var5        Var6        Var3, Var5, Var6
 Var1        NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          Var1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df$variable_7 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x) & x != "No"], collapse = ", "));
df;
#  variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 variable_4 variable_5 variable_6
#1       Var1       Var2       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#2       <NA>         No       <NA>       Var4         No       <NA>
#3       <NA>       <NA>       Var3       <NA>       Var5       Var6
#4       Var1       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#        variable_7
#1       Var1, Var2
#2             Var4
#3 Var3, Var5, Var6
#4             Var1
```

Explanation: Use `apply` and `paste(..., collapse = ", ")` to concatenate all row entries (except `NA`s and `"No"`s) and store in new column `variable_7`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
      cbind(
      variable_1 = c('Var1', NA, NA,'Var1'),
      variable_2 = c('Var2', 'No', NA, NA),
      variable_3 = c(NA, NA, 'Var3', NA),
      variable_4 = c(NA, 'Var4', NA, NA),
      variable_5 = c(NA, 'No', 'Var5', NA),
      variable_6 = c(NA, NA, 'Var6', NA)

    ))
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was expecting, Thx a ton.

Comment: Great, glad to help @Science11

Answer (score 2):

I gather that if there are n rows then objective is to create a an n-vector of comma-separated character strings  of those values in each row that contain the characters `Var`.  (If you intended some other criterion for separating the desired and undesired values then change the `grep` accordingly.)

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) toString(grep("Var", x, value = TRUE)))
## [1] "Var1, Var2"       "Var4"             "Var3, Var5, Var6" "Var1"
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `dplyr`. `df4` is the final output. Please see how I created the data frame `df`. The `cbind` is not required, and it would be great to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to prevent the creation of factor columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(ID = 1:n()) 

df3 <- df2 %>%
  gather(Variable, Value, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!Value %in% "No") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(variable_7 = toString(Value))

df4 <- df2 %>% 
  left_join(df3, by = "ID") %>%
  select(-ID) 

df4
#   variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 variable_4 variable_5 variable_6       variable_7
# 1       Var1       Var2       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       Var1, Var2
# 2       <NA>         No       <NA>       Var4         No       <NA>             Var4
# 3       <NA>       <NA>       Var3       <NA>       Var5       Var6 Var3, Var5, Var6
# 4       Var1       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>             Var1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
    variable_1 = c('Var1', NA, NA,'Var1'),
    variable_2 = c('Var2', 'No', NA, NA),
    variable_3 = c(NA, NA, 'Var3', NA),
    variable_4 = c(NA, 'Var4', NA, NA),
    variable_5 = c(NA, 'No', 'Var5', NA),
    variable_6 = c(NA, NA, 'Var6', NA),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `data.table` 'reshap'-ing approach rather than a loop/apply

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, id := .I][
    melt(df, id.vars = "id")[grepl("Var", value), .(variable_7 = paste0(value, collapse = ",")), by = .(id)]
    , on = "id"
    , nomatch = 0
    ][order(id)]


#    variable_1 variable_2 variable_3 variable_4 variable_5 variable_6 id     variable_7
# 1:       Var1       Var2         NA         NA         NA         NA  1      Var1,Var2
# 2:         NA         No         NA       Var4         No         NA  2           Var4
# 3:         NA         NA       Var3         NA       Var5       Var6  3 Var3,Var5,Var6
# 4:       Var1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA  4           Var1
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it seems like `No` was removed during the process.

Comment: @www - I (maybe incorrectly) _thought_ that was part of the requirement

Comment: OP's expected output still has "No", but it is something minor and it does not affect the effectiveness of your solution.

Comment: @www - in `variable_7` column? I've maintained them in `variable_5` and `variable_2`

Comment: I think it is good to keep `No` on the second row of both 'variable_5' and 'variable_2', which is their original positions.

Comment: @www - I think there's some confusion, but I've added `order(id)` to the chain to keep the ordering :)