# How to combine data frame columns where each represents a different response value?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have demographic survey data in which responses for variable `X` were recorded into 3 separate columns. `col1` contains only 1, `col2` only 2 and `col3` contains everything else. There is no overlap of responses so when the respondent answered "1" cells for `col2` and `col3` in that same row are empty. I'd like to combine all 3 columns (there are 3000+ responses so doing this manually is out of the question). I should note that there are 100+ columns in this data frame and I will need to use this on other variables as well.

I attempted `gather()` and `apply()` commands without much luck.

(see this question for reference: [r collapsing data from multiple columns into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763452/r-collapsing-data-from-multiple-columns-into-one/47763479#47763479?newreg=303798a4255449e0940e458f1125a058))

The apply command combined EVERY column, so I'm guessing I just need to fix my parameters? Wasn't sure how to do this (a bit of a newbie here).

```
df$New <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))
```

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share a portion of your data with `dput(head(df))`. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good R question, it's pretty hard to tell from your post what it is that you're asking for.

Comment: `apply(df[,1:3],...` will do it using just columns 1 to 3

Comment: @astrofunkswag thanks! will do for next time

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `gather() %>% summarise(paste(..., collapse = ", "))`? I am using the example you linked to above.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tibble(
    id = 1:4,
    variable_1 = c('Var1', NA, NA,'Var1'),
    variable_2 = c('Var2', 'No', NA, NA),
    variable_3 = c(NA, NA, 'Var3', NA),
    variable_4 = c(NA, 'Var4', NA, NA),
    variable_5 = c(NA, 'No', 'Var5', NA),
    variable_6 = c(NA, NA, 'Var6', NA) 
  )


df %>% 
  # pivot everything besides id
  gather(var, response, -id) %>%
  # optional
  filter(!is.na(response)) %>% 
  # the method
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(sentence = paste(response, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup()

#    id sentence        
#     1 Var1, Var2      
#     2 No, Var4, No    
#     3 Var3, Var5, Var6
#     4 Var1
```