# Collapse multiple columns into one column based on values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, merge, multiple-columns

I have `data.frame` `df1`:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(apple = c('0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1'),
      banana = c('1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'),
      cherry = c('0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'),
      date = c('0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'))
 rownames(df1) <- c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten')
```

How can I substitute all 'ones' in each column with the column name and then collapse the column into one new column? Expected result is `df2`:

```
 df2 <- data.frame(fruit = c('banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'apple', 'banana', 
      'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'apple'))
 rownames(df2) <- c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 
      'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten')
```

I found the second step here ([r collapsing data from multiple columns into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763452/r-collapsing-data-from-multiple-columns-into-one)) but I don't quite get there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `max.col` to subset the `names`, create a `data.frame` out of it with corresponding `rownames`.

```
> (res <- data.frame(fruit=names(df1)[max.col(df1)]) |> `rownames<-`(rownames(df1)))
       fruit
one   banana
two   cherry
three   date
four   apple
five  banana
six    apple
seven banana
eight cherry
nine    date
ten    apple
> all.equal(df2, res)
[1] TRUE
```

### Benchmark

Seems *user2974951*'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77756667/6574038) (denoted as *arr.ind*) is fastest (despite some strange outliers).

```
> arr.ind1 <- \(df1) {
+   df2 <- as.data.frame(which(df1 == 1, arr.ind=TRUE))
+   df2 <- df2[order(df2$row), ]
+   df2$fruit <- colnames(df1)[df2$col]
+   df2[, 3, drop=FALSE]
+ }
> arr.ind2 <- \(df1) {
+   df2 <- as.data.frame(which(df1 == 1, arr.ind=TRUE))
+   df2 <- df2[order(df2$row), ]
+   df2$fruit <- colnames(df1)[df2$col]
+   subset(df2, select=fruit)
+ }
> library(dplyr) |> suppressPackageStartupMessages()
> library(tidyr) |> suppressPackageStartupMessages()
> set.seed(42)
> DF1 <- df1[sample.int(nrow(df1), 1e4, replace=TRUE), ]
> options(width=200)
> (mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   arr.ind1=arr.ind1(DF1),
+   arr.ind2=arr.ind2(DF1),
+   max.col=data.frame(fruit=names(DF1)[max.col(DF1)]) |> `rownames<-`(rownames(DF1)),
+   max.col2=data.frame(fruit=names(DF1)[max.col(DF1)], row.names=rownames(DF1)),
+   max.col3=setNames(as.data.frame(names(DF1)[max.col(DF1)], row.names=rownames(DF1)), 'fruit'),
+   max.col4=setNames(as.data.frame(names(DF1)[max.col(DF1)]), 'fruit') |> `rownames<-`(rownames(DF1)),
+   tidy=DF1 %>%
+     transmute(across(apple:date, ~case_when(. == 1 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
+     unite(fruit, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' '),
+   check='equivalent'))
```

```
$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval  cld
 arr.ind1  2.838674  2.891762  3.122499  2.944602  3.135042  11.327219   100 a   
 arr.ind2  3.360616  3.417063  3.731845  3.471011  3.681735  13.014652   100 ab  
  max.col  4.823824  4.911244  5.049284  5.002576  5.132965   5.571004   100  bc 
 max.col2  5.209733  5.407884  5.542997  5.453691  5.604758   6.110364   100   c 
 max.col3  4.502090  4.573133  4.668055  4.610790  4.696504   5.486427   100  bc 
 max.col4  4.766816  4.832869  5.235595  4.887230  5.033407  32.472803   100  bc 
     tidy 66.249594 69.793587 73.463189 71.997308 73.727147 145.391572   100    d


> x11(); microbenchmark:::boxplot.microbenchmark(subset(mb, expr != 'tidy') |> transform(expr=droplevels(expr)))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(apple = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "1"), banana = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "0"), cherry = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0", "0"), date = c("0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("one", "two", "three", 
"four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"))
```

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez It's about fifteen times faster than the tidy solution.

Comment: +1 But why not just use the `row.names` argument? `data.frame(fruit=names(df1)[max.col(df1)], row.names=rownames(df1))`

Comment: @RobertHacken Thanks, definitely more concise. However for some reason it's slower,  I've taken it up in the benchmark.

Comment: Interesting, looking into its source code, `data.frame()` does many things one of which is checking if there are duplicates among the row names, which is probably why supplying them as an argument results in slower execution. An even faster approach (not that these small differences would matter much in practice..) would be using `as.data.frame()` (more specifically `as.data.frame.integer()` in this case) which is a much more lightweight function: `setNames(as.data.frame(names(df1)[max.col(df1)], row.names=rownames(df1)), 'fruit')`

Comment: @RobertHacken I think now you've nailed it, `as.data.frame` appears to be fastest.

Comment: @RobertHacken Thanks, fixed. `max.col3` is your variant, `max.col4` again uses `\`rownames<-()\`` function, but it's slower this time.

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply`.

```
> apply(df1 == 1, 1, function(x) {colnames(df1)[x]})
     one      two    three     four     five      six    seven    eight     nine      ten 
"banana" "cherry"   "date"  "apple" "banana"  "apple" "banana" "cherry"   "date"  "apple"
```

another option using `which`

```
> df2 <- as.data.frame(which(df1 == 1, arr.ind=TRUE))
> df2 <- df2[order(df2$row), ]
> df2$fruit <- colnames(df1)[df2$col]
      row col  fruit
one     1   2 banana
two     2   3 cherry
three   3   4   date
four    4   1  apple
five    5   2 banana
six     6   1  apple
seven   7   2 banana
eight   8   3 cherry
nine    9   4   date
ten    10   1  apple
```

Comment: The `which`  one is amazingly fast, see in the [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77756765/6574038).

Answer (score 1):

Here is `tidyverse` way using `transmute` and `unite`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  transmute(across(apple:date, ~case_when(. == 1 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
  unite(fruit, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')
```

```
       fruit
one   banana
two   cherry
three   date
four   apple
five  banana
six    apple
seven banana
eight cherry
nine    date
ten    apple
```